# Compiling a .java file with incorrect package name

Tags: java, compilation, directory, package

In the book "OCA Oracle Certified Associate Java SE 8 Programmer I Study Guide Exam 1Z0-808" by Boyarsky and Selikoff I encountered a confusing question in the review exam for Chapter I:

*14. Given the following class in the file /my/directory/named/A/Bird.java:*

`INSERT CODE HERE
public class Bird { }`

*Which of the following replaces* `INSERT CODE HERE` *if we compile from /my/directory? (Choose all that apply)*

*A.* `package my.directory.named.a;`

*B.* `package my.directory.named.A;`

*C.* `package named.a;`

*D.* `package named.A;`

*E.* `package a;`

*F.* `package A;`

*G.* `Does not compile`

The book states that the correct answer is just D. (we'll ignore the fact that they wrote "Choose all that apply" despite stating that they would only do so if there were more than 1 answer, earlier in the book), with the explanation:

*D. The package name represents any folders underneath the current path, which is
named.A in this case. Option B is incorrect because package names are case sensitive,
just like variable names and other identifiers.*

I'm totally confused with this on various levels:

1. I tried to compile the file from /my/directory using `javac /named/A/Bird.java` and the code compiles successfully with any of the answers above. Furthermore, the code compiles no matter what I write after `package` in the first line of the class.
2. Let's assume I completely missed the point in (no pun intended) point 1 and that's not how *we compile from /my/directory*, then I've got these questions:

   - How do *we compile from /my/directory*?
   - Why is the option B. incorrect? The explanation they provided for B.  makes no sense, obviously.

Can someone shed some light on this matter?

Comment: Well, since nobody's taking any interest here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is the question is wrong.

A single class can be compiled from anywhere, without considering the package hierarchy **if** it has no references to other custom classes (so you can use `String` etc.). This is because it doesn't need to do any lookups for other classes, so there's no need for anything special in the compile-time classpath. As soon as you add a reference to let's say class `named.A.Rock` the compilation will no longer work, because the directory hierarchy doesn't match the package hierarchy (unless you put `Bird` in `named.A` package as well).

So the example in the question is just bad. As soon as you add a reference to another class and the package hierarchy starts to matter, `D` is the correct answer. The question is a bit poor since you can set the compile time classpath explicitly, at which point the concept of "current directory" doesn't matter one bit and all of the answers would be valid.

Comment: Wouldn't you think they would test this stuff before printing it? Shame on the authors, and the technical reviewers too. What other drivel is there? and how many people have failed OCA because of wrong questions like this?